# What's the difference between '=' operator and LIKE when not using wildcards

Tags: mysql, sql, operators, view

I do this question, because I can't found a question with the same reason. The reason is when I use `LIKE`, I get CONSISTENT RESULTS, and when I use (=) operator I get INCONSISTENT RESULTS.

**THE CASE**
I have a BIG VIEW (viewX) with multiple inner joins and left joins, where some columns have null values, because the database definition allows for that.

1. When I open this VIEW I see for example: 8 rows as result.
2. When I run for example: `select * from viewX where column_int = 34 and type_string = 'xyz'`, this query shows me 100 rows, that aren't defined in the result of the view. [INCONSISTENT]

BUT

1. When I run `select * from viewX where column_int = 34 and type_string like 'xyz'`, this query show me only 4 rows, that is defined in the view when I opened (see 1.) [CONSISTENT]

Does anyone idea, of what is happening here?

Comment: can you post your view definition?

Comment: The view definition is SO BIG, please, try to understan the problem with the question text, the VIEW results are consistent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation.....

'Per the SQL standard, LIKE performs matching on a per-character basis, thus it can produce results different from the = comparison operator: '

more importantly (when using LIKE):

'**string comparisons are not case sensitive unless one of the operands is a binary string**'

from :
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html

Answer (score 2):

[Per the MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like) `LIKE` does function differently than `=`, especially when you have trailing or leading spaces.

You need to post your actual query but I'm guessing it's related to the known variances.